# Object with texture in Look Dev mode appears black in render mode

Tags: texturing

So I am rendering this character. For some reason it's rendering black but in Look Dev it shows the proper texture. Why?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: maybe you have overlapping faces, please check or share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @moonboots Added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have given thickness to your object, you have 2 meshes almost overlapping, one with black color faces, the other with colored faces. The mesh with black faces has its faces inverted. As you've enabled the *Backface Culling* option in the *Material > Viewport Display*, we can't see these black faces in *Material Preview*, only the colored ones beneath.

To fix that, either remove the black mesh, or, if you need to keep them for some reason, select all your pieces, switch to *Edit* mode and recalculate the normals.